# Multicast DNS really slow to respond in macOS Mojave

Tags: networking, macos, dns, mdns

I have a Macbook Air running 10.14 Mojave, and an iPhone with a certain app that needs to sync via WebDAV with the Mac from time to time. The way I configured it is to add in the app's settings `http://my-macbook-air.local` as the WebDAV server. Both devices are connected to the same local subnet, using 192.168.1.X as the IP range, etc.

Anyway, this didn't happen when the Mac was running 10.13, but ever since I upgraded to Mojave, most of the time the iPhone takes forever to find the Mac via multicast DNS. I try to sync and it says that it can't find `http://my-macbook-air.local` for about 5 minutes... until it finally resolves. I have also checked using a Ping app in my iPhone: I tell it to ping `my-macbook-air.local` and it doesn't find the host for minutes... until it finally finds it.

What's going on?

Comment: This sounds [distressingly similar to a common problem across DNS clients on different OSes](https://superuser.com/questions/355625/unable-to-resolve-foo-local-domain-names), but this is all Apple-land, so I'd expect MDNS to work flawlessly. Personally, I set up an Unbound server on a Raspberry Pi to work around this class of problems, but I can't blame you if you don't want to mess with that.

Comment: Can you ping 224.0.0.1 (the "all hosts" multicast address) from your iPhone for a while to see how reliable multicasts are on your network? There are lots of buggy Wi-Fi APs that don't do multicast reliably, which makes mDNS unreliable. Doing multicast pings will help determine if this is a general multicast problem or a specific mDNS problem.

Comment: @Spiff. mmm, interesting. I have another Mac Mini in my local subnet, running 10.11.6, and if I ping 224.0.0.1 from the iPhone, I get a consistent response from it, but I get almost nothing from the Macbook. I would say that I get one ping back from the Macbook for every 20 pings from the Mac Mini.

Comment: Unfortunately mDNS uses a type of multicast group that doesn't actually have an opt-in mechanism – it's always multicast to literally all hosts – so maybe the router is not so much "outright buggy" as much as "trying to save battery by batching multicasts and overdoing it"...

Comment: @user1686: my router is plugged to the wall, it doesn't use batteries. Also, why did it work perfectly in 10.13 and it doesn't in 10.14?

Comment: I meant save battery _for Wi-Fi clients_. For devices like smartphones, having to receive frequent multicasts or broadcasts means spending much less time in deep sleep modes. So many routers and APs have features meant to minimize this, and sometimes they overdo it. (In fact some of them just outright block LAN→WiFi multicast by default...)